I want the timer to start after .exitA is clicked
There is a timer that appears on the screen after clicking .exitA, 1st button.
I want the timer to start after that button is clicked.
The timer should start after clicking .exitA:
Where the numbers appear on the screen going up.
Clicking on the screen/body, stops it.
https://jsfiddle.net/87jvr3uh/
Right now, it stops after that button is clicked.
<div class="outer-containerA">

  <div class="video-containerA">
    <button class="exitA" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Exit"></button>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="video playA"></div>
      <div class="curtain"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="playA"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="video-containerB hide">
    <button class="exitB" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Exit"></button>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="video playB"></div>
      <div class="curtain"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="playB"></div>

    <h2>Click anywhere to stop the timer</h2>

    <p id="timer"></p>

    <script>
      let seconds = 0;
      let timerId = setInterval(updateTimer, 100);

      function updateTimer() {
        seconds += 0.1;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds.toFixed(1) + " seconds";
      }

      document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
        clearInterval(timerId);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML += " (stopped)";
      });

    </script>
  </div>

Here is the standalone timer code by itself:
https://jsfiddle.net/o4qLxnr8/2/

Try this fiddle:
jsfiddle.net/gaxn7j2L/1

Can you show me how in the fiddle please? https://jsfiddle.net/87jvr3uh/

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gaxn7j2L/1/
